# Como pegar o último tweet?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Preciso implementar uma função no meu projeto para pegar o último tweet, porém todas tentativas sem êxito, alguém poderia me passar uma função para exibir o último tweet?

Comment: Não estas a usar nenhuma API?

Comment: não, estava tentando com essa função:             function UltimoTweet($usuario){
 $url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/$usuario.xml?count=1";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Erro ao conectar.");
 foreach($xml->status as $status){
  $ultimo = $status->text;
 }
 echo $ultimo;
}

Comment: Se você quiser tem um link que pode te ajudar http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/ porém está em inglês.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo Roberto, testarei aqui.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use alguma biblioteca PHP que dê suporte ao Tweeter API:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php

Segue abaixo um exemplo utilizando a [classe TwitterOAuth, de Abraham Williams](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/):

```
# Carregar a classe do Twitter API
require_once('TwitterOAuth.php');

# Definir constantes
define('TWEET_LIMIT', 5);
define('TWITTER_USERNAME', 'YOUR_TWITTER');
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'YOUR_KEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'YOUR_TOKEN');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'YOUR_TOKEN_SECRET');

# Criar conexão
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

# Usar SSL/TLS
$twitter->ssl_verifypeer = true;

# Carregar os Tweets
$tweets = $twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => TWITTER_USERNAME, 'exclude_replies' => 'true', 'include_rts' => 'false', 'count' => TWEET_LIMIT));

# Exemplo de saída
if(!empty($tweets)) {
    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {

        # Acessando como um objeto
        $tweetText = $tweet->text;

        # Tornando links ativos
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/(http://|(www.))(([^s<]{4,68})[^s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $tweetText);

        # "Linkificar" menções a usuários
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/@(w+)/", '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $tweetText);

        # "Linkificar" tags
        $tweetText = preg_replace("/#(w+)/", '<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>', $tweetText);

        # Enviar saída
        echo $tweetText;

    }
}
```

Fonte: http://www.aljtmedia.com/blog/displaying-latest-tweets-using-the-twitter-api-v11-in-php

Para usar essa biblioteca, você precisa registrar uma aplicação no Twitter para obter a chave e o token de acesso: https://apps.twitter.com/